# Sum of amicable numbers from 1-100,000 (AP CS-A)

Tags: java

Our task in class today was to find the sum of all amicable numbers from 1-100000.

```
 int sum = 0;
        for(int i = 1; i < 100000; i++ ) {
            int a = 1;
            for (int j = 2; j <= Math.sqrt(i); j++) {
                if (i % j == 0) {
                    if (j == (i / j))
                        a += j;
                    else
                        a += (j + i / j);
                }
            }

            int b = 1;
            for (int j = 2; j <= Math.sqrt(a); j++) {
                if (a % j == 0) {
                    if (j == (a / j))
                        b += j;
                    else
                        b += (j + a / j);
                }
            }
            if(a==b) sum += a;
        }
        
        System.out.println(sum);
```

This is the code I made in class today. Unfortunately it did not work and not it's homework.

Amicable numbers are defined by: [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amicable_numbers#:~:text=Amicable%20numbers%20are%20two%20different,is%20(220%2C%20284).&text=For%20example%2C%20the%20proper%20divisors,aliquot%20sequence%20of%20period%202](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amicable_numbers#:%7E:text=Amicable%20numbers%20are%20two%20different,is%20(220%2C%20284).&text=For%20example%2C%20the%20proper%20divisors,aliquot%20sequence%20of%20period%202).

I need to accomplish this goal without using helper methods and not double counting possibilities, but I somehow keep getting wrong answers. Unfortunately, we can only use arrays and ArrayList for data structures to keep it simple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a boolean array to keep track of which values you already counted. Here is a working solution:

```
        boolean[] arr = new boolean[100000];
        for(int i = 1; i < 100000; i++ ) {
            int a = 1;
            for (int j = 2; j <= Math.sqrt(i); j++) {
                if (i % j == 0) {
                    if (j == (i / j))
                        a += j;
                    else
                        a += (j + i / j);
                }
            }

            int b = 1;
            for (int j = 2; j <= Math.sqrt(a); j++) {
                if (a % j == 0) {
                    if (j == (a / j))
                        b += j;
                    else
                        b += (j + a / j);
                }
            }

            if(i == b && i != a) {
                if(!arr[i])
                    arr[i] = true;
                if(!arr[b])
                    arr[b] = true;
            }
        }

        int sum = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            if(arr[i] == true) {
                sum += i;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(sum);
```

To make this work for numbers 1 to n you can replace the array length and the 100000 in the for loop with a method parameter.

Comment: Thanks so much for the solution man! Works like a charm!